# FileZIller Server failure with PHP built FTP Client

Tags: php, ftp

I have downloaded ZF2 and I am making use of the [nicolab/php-ftp-client](https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client) library. This library works with our staging server but the issue is with the FTP Server configured locally. If I am using FileZille Client I can be able to enter my local File Server but not with PHP.

Below is a line I have in one of my test classes:

```
$handler = $this->ns->connect( '127.0.0.1:54218' )->login( '***', '***' );
```

Ofcourse that line works with the remote server but the local one.

PHPUnit gives me the following error:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.E                                                    2 /(100%)

Time: 2.59 seconds, Memory: 8.25MB

There was 1 error:

  1) ApplicationTest\Service\RemoteClientConnectionTest::testRemoteClientConnection
     FtpClient\FtpException: Unable to connect

D:\web\www2\zend-file-manager\vendor\nicolab\
  php-ftp-client\src\FtpClient\FtpClient.php:162
D:\web\www2\zend-file-manager\module\SparkleRemoteClient\test\
 SparkleRemoteClientTest\Service\RemoteClientConnectionTest.php:22

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.
```

Meanwhile FileZille Client gives me this output:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:54218...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

I am building a File Manager with Zend for our client and I need to have an FTP Server setup locally so that I do not run a risk of doing the wrong things with the staging and or live one.

Looking forward to hearing what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check function definition

```
public function connect($host, $ssl = false, $port = 21, $timeout = 90)
```

So You need to use something like

```
$handler = $this->ns->connect('127.0.0.1',false,54218)->login( '***', '***' );
```

Comment: Thank you @Goerge this worked like a charm. I do not know what was going on my mind because I checked the function definition but my interpretation did not bring me to this. Thanks again.

Comment: @LuyandaSiko no problems, mate, sometimes it happens with all of us ;) Also, please, don't forget to close the issue at GitHub. Have a nice day!